# Command prompt closes after I run my.exe from python script

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir("C:\\code\\runcommand\\")
command = "my.exe"
subprocess.Popen(command)
```

with above code my.exe runs on command prompt and gets closed. How to prevent command prompt from closing.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want leave open the command prompt you can add `input()` as last line ([read more...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)). Then cmd will be close after hitting any key.